# how to simulate a ROC curve with a specified AUC

Tags: r, roc

I want to simulate a ROC curve with 0.8 AUC. Does anyone know how to do it?

say, I have 100 data point. My binary class distribution is 9:1. So I can do:

```
label = c(rep(1, 10), rep(0, 90))
```

How do I generate a sequence of probabilities so that the resulting ROC curve has AUC 0.8.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you’re trying to do but a ROC curve depends on a binary classifier. Which binary classifier are you using (e.g. logistic regression, random forest etc.)? Can you include some sample code?

Comment: Roc only need a binary variable and a continuous variable

Comment: No I don't think that's correct. A ROC curve shows the true positive rate vs the false positive rate. My question is: How do you calculate the TPR/FPR? You need some classification model that allows you to characterise how many true/false positives you have, *given that model*. Consequently a ROC curve (or the AUC) is a measure of the performance *of your classification model*. What kind of classification model are you using?

Comment: You should look into this subject more.

Comment: No worries; good luck with your post.

Comment: You might see the answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/424213/20338